# Text is doesn't fill the whole div, only a portion in the middle

Tags: html, css, laravel, tailwind-css

In short, my problem is this:

I'm using TailWind on Laravel, I can't get the text inside the border to fit the whole div he's in, and it's weirdly centered this way where the amount of characters per line is limited

[image: Tracklist]

I tried many approaches like changing and trying different values of padding and margin but I was unsuccessful, it only makes the div bigger but the text is still awfully centered and limited.

the code portion is as follows:

```
<div class="mx-4">
    <x-card class="p-10">
        <div
            class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center"
        >
            <img
                class="w-48 mr-6 mb-6"
                src="{{$album->logo? asset('storage/'.$album->logo) : asset('/images/noalbum.png')}}"
                alt=""
            />

            <h3 class="text-2xl mb-2">{{$album->title}}</h3>
            <div class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">{{$album->artist}}</div>
            <x-insidetags :tagscsv="$album->tags"/>
            <div class=" w-full mb-6 mt-5">
                <h3 class="text-3xl font-bold">
                    About the album
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div> 
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="px-20 text-lg border border-black text-left">
                        <h3 class="font-bold">Track List :</h3>
                        @foreach($tracks as $track)
                            <p>- {{$track}}</p>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-lg space-y-6 ml-10">
                        <div class="text-left py-10">
                            {{$album->description}}
                        </div>

                        <a
                            href="{{$album->website}}"
                            target="_blank"
                            class=" bg-black text-laravel mt-16 py-2 px-10 rounded-xl hover:opacity-80"
                            ><i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i> Visit RateYourMusic page</a
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

For refrence I'm trying to create something like this, but only with the name of the tracks for the moment

[image: tracklists]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, added flex 1 1 0% and flex 4 1 0% to the two divs

```
<div class=" text-lg shadow-xl text-left flex-1 h-fit p-5">
                        <h3 class="font-bold">Track List :</h3>
                        @foreach($tracks as $track)
                            <p>- {{$track}}</p>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-lg ml-10 flex-[4_1_0%]">
                        <div class="text-left py-10">
                            {{$album->description}}
                        </div>

                        <a
                            href="{{$album->website}}"
                            target="_blank"
                            class=" bg-black text-laravel mt-16 py-2 px-10 rounded-xl hover:opacity-80"
                            ><i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i> Visit RateYourMusic page</a
                        >
                    </div>
```